# Beginner: Is this good encryption?

Tags: encryption, .net, pbkdf2

I've managed to knock together some code to encrypt/decrypt a string and I'm wondering whether I've done a good job at it. Is it truly secure, in other words.

I read in a StackOverflow post that reusing the IV is bad practice and should be avoided. I can't say for sure, but I believe that's what I'm doing here. Confirm/deny?

That said, wouldn't using a different IV for each operation render the encrypted stream undecryptable? I'm afraid I don't know as much about this as I'd like.

Here's the code:

```
Private Function Crypt(InBytes As Byte(), Password As String, Action As EncryptionActions) As Byte()
  Dim oCryptoTransform As ICryptoTransform
  Dim oDesProvider As AesCryptoServiceProvider

  Dim _
    iBlockSize,
    iKeySize,
    iSize As Integer

  Dim _
    aSalt,
    aKey,
    aIV As Byte()

  oDesProvider = New AesCryptoServiceProvider
  oDesProvider.Mode = CipherMode.CBC

  aSalt = {&H10, &H20, &H12, &H23, &H37, &HA4, &HC5, &HA6, &HF1, &HF0, &HEE, &H21, &H22, &H45}

  For iSize = 1024 To 1 Step -1
    If oDesProvider.ValidKeySize(iSize) Then
      iKeySize = iSize
      Exit For
    End If
  Next

  iBlockSize = oDesProvider.BlockSize

  With New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Password, aSalt, 12345)
    aKey = .GetBytes(iKeySize \ 8)
    aIV = .GetBytes(iBlockSize \ 8)
  End With

  Select Case Action
    Case EncryptionActions.Encrypt : oCryptoTransform = oDesProvider.CreateEncryptor(aKey, aIV)
    Case EncryptionActions.Decrypt : oCryptoTransform = oDesProvider.CreateDecryptor(aKey, aIV)
    Case Else : Throw New ArgumentException("Invalid encryption action specified.")
  End Select

  Using oOutStream As New MemoryStream
    Using oCryptoStream As New CryptoStream(oOutStream, oCryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
      oCryptoStream.Write(InBytes, 0, InBytes.Length)
    End Using

    Return oOutStream.ToArray
  End Using
End Function
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at the rule one of crypto: [NEVER roll your own](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/a/915/9778) :)

Comment: @pnp Even if you don't you have to find a good existing implementation. Which is almost as hard.

Comment: "NEVER roll your own." OK, I'll buy that. Sounds good and I agree. But where does one draw that line? In this code, for example, I'm using the standard .NET libraries; couldn't one say that I haven't rolled my own? If I have however, then Rule #1 precludes using these libraries, rendering them ineffective. You've got me curious. Please elaborate.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - What's your opinion of ProtectedData.Unprotect()? I found that after I wrote this method--which I've put on ice for the time being as a result, pending the outcome of this investigation.

Comment: @InteXX It isn't a general purpose encryption routine. It's mainly useful if you want a per-process, per-windows-user-account or per-machine key that's supplied by the OS. I'd only use it to encrypt my own keys, not data.

Comment: @pnp - I'm still learning how the notification system works, so I don't think you saw my question. I'm concerned: is what I've done above (not me really, it's mostly from MSDN samples) considered 'rolling one's own'? This sounds like a tough call.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - I'd pretty much figured that; pardon me, I didn't clarify. For the current context--encrypting user passwords for automated signon to a third-party server--I think it'll do. Especially now that my code above has now been shown to be insufficient. The worst that can come of it is that sometime down the road a user could be prompted to enter his password again. What I was asking your opinion about was the encryption strength of the output of ProtectedData.Protect().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know .net so I don't understand the code in details but as far as I can see there are at least the following problems:

- You are not using authenticated encryption. You should use a MAC like HMAC to detect manipulations of the ciphertext. Otherwise, an attacker could manipulate the ciphertext so that it is decrypted to a plausible plaintext.
- For DES there exists weak keys. If you're unlucky your derived key is a weak one but the probability to get a weak key usually is negligible. Furthermore, you should use AES instead of 3DES.
- I can't see which cipher mode you use. ECB is not recommended. Today, CBC or CTR are recommended by most cryptographers.

The way you should do encryption is as follows:

- select a key at random or derive a key from a password
- use AES-256 in CBC mode with PKCS#5 padding
- select an IV at random
- encrypt the data
- compute an HMAC over the IV + ciphertext
- send IV + ciphertext + HMAC

When receiving the ciphertext:

- check that the HMAC of IV + ciphertext is correct
- decrypt the ciphertext

Comment: The OP's code uses PBKDF2 this is what RFC 2898 is. PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1 is called with a fixed salt and iteration count this is used to provide both the key and the IV. Thus the same encryption key and IV are used for a given password.

Comment: "send IV + ciphertext + HMAC" At decryption IV is 8 bytes, so that's easy--but how do you know where [ciphertext] ends and [HMAC] begins? (HMAC is used in signing certificates, yes?)

Comment: I've edited the code to set the cipher mode to CBC, as you suggest. Thanks.

Comment: I just noticed in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/61yeb601%28v=VS.110,d=hv.2%29.aspx) that the Mode property default is CBC. Nevertheless, it's probably good to explicitly set it in code.

Comment: @InteXX you need a proper data serialization scheme. As DanielE pointed out, you should be using AesCryptoServiceProvider, not TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider. If you do use HMAC, you need to generate a key for it, too.

Comment: The last sentence in my previous comment might be misleading. As a general rule, you should use either an encryption mode which provides authentication such as GCM or use a MAC.

Comment: @erwan-legrand - "...a proper data serialization scheme." Sounds good, how/where do I learn about creating a good one? Do we find an example in what Scott Chamberlain is talking about below with `Salt_Bytes + IV_Bytes + PBKDF2_Itteration_Count + Encrypted_Bytes`? Assuming so, this would seem to mean that I'd have to decide on a standard and stick with it; data that I will have encrypted some time earlier will be impossible to decrypt if I don't use that same scheme. FWIW, I suppose I could head this problem off by doing something like storing a scheme version in the final product.

Comment: @erwan-legrand - "As a general rule..." I'm having a tough time grasping all of this. Are you aware of any code samples for review that demonstrate these concepts? It's clear by now that the snippet above that I punched together by scanning through the MSDN samples doesn't make the grade.

Comment: @erwan-legrand - I've updated the code to use AesCryptoServiceProvider, as you recommend.

Comment: @InteXX I would suggest using a higher-level crypto library. KeyCzar is such a library, but unfortunately it does not support .Net. I'm afraid I cannot be of much help here. I rarely use .Net myself.

Comment: @InteXX Alternatively, you could manage your passwords with Password Safe and access the password from your .Net code using the [Password Safe Database Reader Library in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20892/Password-Safe-Database-Reader-Library-in-C-for-NET). Would this work for you?

Comment: @ErwanLegrand - Password Safe Reader looks VERY interesting. I'll probably eventually end up contributing the Writer that he's asking for. Thanks for the lead.

Answer (score 2):

Your question lacks context. What exactly are you trying to achieve? More precisely what attacks are you trying to defend against?

As I understand it, your code always use the same key and initialization vector.

Both the salt parameter passed to PBKDF2 and the IV passed to the block cipher should be generated using a properly seeded CSPRNG. In .Net use [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Edit:

The salt and IV are not secrets. They should be part of the message or file or whatever this is your code produces.

One more comment: you should probably not use a hard-coded number of PBKDF2 iterations. The number of iterations required increases over time as hardware becomes faster. Thus the number of iterations should also be part of the message/file/record/whatever.

Comment: Context: This is a monolithic desktop app that encrypts and stores a password for later automated signon to a remote third-party server not under my control. Repeated Salt/IV: Wouldn't using new values for these for each operation render the ciphertext undecryptable? Or maybe I'm misunderstanding your advice.

Comment: More context: The attacker will get the Byte() array from the Windows registry.

Comment: For the random salt/IV issue, as said in the edit the SALT and IV are not secrects your data will likely look like `Salt_bytes + IV_Bytes + PBKDF2_Itteration_Count + Encrypted_Bytes` you then read off those three pieces of information from the file when you decrypt.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain: exactly, yes!

Comment: @InteXX: The answer is in Scott Chamberlain's comment if this was not clear enough in my reply. **Do not reuse salts or IVs**, ever.

Comment: @scott-chamberlain - So `Salt` should be a random byte array, but always the same length; `IV` is always 8 bytes. Correct so far? `Iterations` is where I get hung up. Are you embedding the actual integer value in the final product? If so, how do you know at decryption time how many digits to account for and where they are, so that you can properly decrypt `Encrypted_Bytes`? Such a design must be what Erwan is talking about when he cautions that I need a proper serialization scheme, yes?

Comment: @erwan-legrand - "Do not reuse salts or IVs, ever." Fair 'nuff. Just to clarify--'cause I'm still getting my head around it--this means reuse across multiple _encryption_ sessions, yes? Because we need that same salt/IV pair for decryption. The raw data can be random, but as long as it's the same length each time we can know how to split the combined result.

Comment: No, you do not re-use it ever, even across multiple session. Either use a fixed length or prepend the length before the bytes so it will be `Salt_length (32 bits large) + Salt_bytes (Salt_length bytes large) + IV_Length (32 bits large) + IV_Bytes (IV_Length bytes large) + PBKDF2_Itteration_Count (32 bits large) + Encrypted_Bytes (The rest of the file)`

Comment: @InteXX **You shall not reuse IVs, ever**. An encryption session consisting of several message can use the same encryption key to encrypt several messages. As an example, TLS implementations usually negotiate a new session key after 5 minutes. You could see this as a performance-security trade-off: generating a new key for each message would be too costly. But **reusing an IV would break the encryption**. Do not do this!

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - "No, you do not re-use it ever, even across multiple session" I guess I'm not understanding the concept of _reuse_. Let's say we generate a unique salt and IV and encrypt a string. Then, through some mechanism, we use that same salt and IV to decrypt the string. Have we now _reused_ that salt and IV?

Comment: @ErwanLegrand - "You shall not reuse IVs, ever" I'm probably getting hung up on terminology. See my question to ScottChamberlain--is using a unique salt/IV for a matching encrypt/decrypt set defined as _reuse_?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain = "`Salt_length (32 bits large) + Salt_bytes (Salt_length bytes large) + IV_Length (32 bits large) + IV_Bytes (IV_Length bytes large) + PBKDF2_Itteration_Count (32 bits large) + Encrypted_Bytes (The rest of the file)`" OK, this is starting to make sense now. I truly appreciate your patience and assistance. Now I'm off to figure out how to convert an Integer into a Byte() array. Perfect.

Comment: @InteXX [`BitConverter.GetBytes(yourSaltArray.Length)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4.aspx) and do `int saltLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(encryptionHeaderArray, saltOffset);` to go the other direction.

Comment: @InteXX By reusing I meant reusing for encryption. Of course you need to use the same key (secret) and IV (not secret) to decrypt as was used for encryption.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - "`BitConverter`" Perfect. That's what we'll do then. Thanks so much to both you and Erwan.

Comment: @ErwanLegrand - OK, I believe I've got a handle on it now. So to wrap up, Scott's `EncryptionHeaderArray + CipherArray` is what you were talking about earlier with your "_proper serialization scheme_" reference, correct? Thanks so much to both you and Scott.